# Why does awaiting a function cause an "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

Why does await specifically cause an invalid left hand assignment?

```
   for(let b = 0; b < uniqueMenuItems.length; b++ )
    {
      uniqueMenuItems[b] = uniqueMenuItems[b].replace(/®.*/, "");
      await drinks[b] = I.scrape({"xpath":".//*[text()=\"" + uniqueMenuItems[b] + "\"]//following::*[@class=\"productControllers custom-product-ctrls\"][1]/div/div/select"}, uniqueMenuItems[b]);
    }
```

The error occurs on this code: "await drinks[b] = I.scrape("

When run without await, drinks variable is filled with promises which is not eexpected I expect string data as should be returned by I.scrape.

I.scrap does this:

```
  async scrape(locator, uniqueMenuItem, I) {
    let driver = this.helpers.Protractor.browser;
    let pricingCalories = [""];
    let selectDropdowns = [""];
    let elementExists;
    //Look for options under the item name, if avilable loop all options and process base price and calories
    driver.element(locator).isPresent().then((result) => {
      //console.log(elementExists); //debug element existance results
      if (result) {
        console.log("Dropdown options exist for locator" + locator);
        selectDropdowns = this.getElementsText(locator);
        for(let a = 0; a < selectDropdowns.length; a++){
          console.log(a);
          I.selectOption({"xpath":"" + locator + ""}, selectDropdowns[a]);
          pricingCalories[a] += selectDropdowns[a];
          pricingCalories[a] += this.getElementsText({"xpath":".//*[text()=\"" + uniqueMenuItem + "\"]/following::*[@class=\"productPrice ng-scope\"][1]"}) + " ";
          pricingCalories[a] += " " + this.getElementsText({"xpath":".//*[text()=\"" + uniqueMenuItem + "\"]/following::*[@class=\"caloriesInfo ng-scope\"][1]"}) + " ";
        }
        return pricingCalories.toString();
      }
      //if select options are unavilable process the visible price and calories 
      else{
      console.log('No options, attempting collection of single item price and calorie data');
      pricingCalories[0] = this.getElementsText({"xpath":".//*[text()=\"" + uniqueMenuItem + "\"]/following::*[@class=\"productPrice ng-scope\"][1]"})  + " ";
      pricingCalories[0] += " " + this.getElementsText({"xpath":".//*[text()=\"" + uniqueMenuItem + "\"]/following::*[@class=\"caloriesInfo ng-scope\"][1]"}) + " ";
      return pricingCalories[0].toString();
      }
      });
  }
```

Comment: You have a typo: `drinks[b] = await I.scrape(...)` the keyword `await` comes after the `=` sign

Comment: thanks that worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to `await drinks[b]` (where `drinks[b]` is treated as a promise) and then assign `I.scrape…` to the result of that.

You can't make assignments to the result of evaluating an expression.

Possibly you want to await the result of the promise `I.scrape…` and then assign **that** to `drinks[b]` in which case you would need:

```
drinks[b] = await I.scrape(
```